Hot-plugg USB device by enabling/disabling USB 5V power over GPIO
We have a USB port on our board, which uses an AP2171 as an integrated high-side power switch for the USB port.
The chip has an enable input, which we can switch by a GPIO output mapped on Linux.
Now if we have a USB device connected, and the enable input of the chip is high, the USB device gets recognized just fine.
If we disconnect the USB device, and reconnect it, we can see that the disconnect and connect udev events are fired.
Now, if we set the GPIO to low, the AP2171 chip will set the USB power to 0V, and the USB device gets disconnected as expected.
But when we re-enable the USB power, the device no longer gets connected. Only a
echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb1/authorized
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb1/authorized

helps to re-enable the USB device.
The question now is, is it valid to just "cut" the power to the USB device? Should the Kernel (5.15.91) be able to handle that? Or do we need to first stop the communication to the USB device?
